# Ubuntu 12.10 USB Graphics Compatibility

Tags: usb, graphics, compatibility, displaylink

I was looking at solutions to connect 2 monitors to 1 USB port and found these:

1) http://www.targus.com/us/productdetail.aspx?regionId=7&sku=ACA039US

2) http://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/USB-3-to-HDMI-DVI-External-Video-Card~USB32HDDVII

These are both displaylink. I have heard that displaylink docks do not work but adapters do. Since these have 2 outputs, I wasn't sure if they are compatible with Ubuntu 12.10. Any Help? If these won't work what will?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, what I found when using a DisplayLink USB monitor is that I could start X on the monitor fine, because DisplayLink has support in the kernel, but I (1) couldn't use my graphics card's acceleration, (2) couldn't easily have the display extend from one regular monitor to the DisplayLink. I was able to eventually get it working, sort of, using screenclone but I couldn't move windows between monitors, get compositing to work, or use xrandr at all. See these questions for some details on setting it up:

- [How do I use a DisplayLink monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40031/how-do-i-use-a-displaylink-monitor)
- [How do I configure a displaylink USB monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98916/how-do-i-configure-a-displaylink-usb-monitor)

It looks like there is a project to get this working better called [hybrid-screenclone](https://github.com/liskin/hybrid-screenclone) which will make it easier to do some of the hacks I described.

Ultimately, I would advise against a DisplayLink setup unless you're willing to try some hacks and experimental proding, and still possibly be let down. Though the chances if you getting it working if you don't want to also use a regular monitor are much better.