# Using AOC USB monitor on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, drivers, monitor

I have recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu 12.10. I have an AOC portable laptop monitor (Model number e1649Fwu), which works solely through USB.

It works fine on Windows, but I cannot work out how to find/install drivers for Ubuntu. I found [this forum thread](http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=2017).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**: It now displays the purple Ubuntu start-up screen, but an error is displayed on the second monitor when login is complete. I get Ubuntu as expected on my primary screen, and on the second screen it gives a general protection fault.

I followed the steps on this Ask Ubuntu question about installing a [USB-link monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98916/how-do-i-configure-a-displaylink-usb-monitor), but the `displaylink.c` file throws C errors when I run:

```
./configure && make && make install
```

I tried to fix these by modifying the C code, but no luck. I also tried using the `xorg.conf` file used in this [tutorial](http://imkiyoung.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/raspberry-pi-and-aoc-e1649fwu-usb-powered-led-monitor/), but this also doesn't work.

Am I right in thinking that it is just a matter of getting the `xorg.conf` file correct now?

This is a picture of the error shown on the second screen:

[image: error on second screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a DisplayLink device, try to use one of the how-to's for DisplayLink & Ubuntu, e.g. [How do I use a DisplayLink monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40031/how-do-i-use-a-displaylink-monitor)

Comment: Thanks, that led me to some more useful information. However, everything I've seen says you should start with:
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-displaylink
This doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.10. I read something about DisplayLink now being included in the Kernel. Does that mean that it's not necessary to install it from xserver first?

Comment: You're right, it should not be necessary anymore because of the kernel driver `udlfb`. (http://libdlo.freedesktop.org/wiki/displaylink-mod). Does your screen turns green? If yes, the kernel successfully loaded the driver. Check loaded modules using `lsmod`.

Comment: Thanks, falstaff. I've edited the original post to summarize progress I've made. If you have more ideas, I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: Here is a photo of the error shown on the 2nd monitor: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByEENivQuwUBZ0VKSEd2LVVad2s

Comment: I have attached your picture to the question for immediate reference. I hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that initially, but had too many links in the question for my reputation.

Answer (score 0):

[how do to install the display drivers for a displaylink usb monitor on 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289018/how-do-to-install-the-display-drivers-for-a-displaylink-usb-monitor-on-13-04)

Some peple are saying it worked on earlier versions of ubuntu with a manual kernal upgrade. Someone else said Fedora 18 supports it out of the box...

Also, here is support for a raspberry pi!!!
http://imkiyoung.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/raspberry-pi-and-aoc-e1649fwu-usb-powered-led-monitor/

Answer (score 0):

Much later but on Ubuntu 20.04, the AOCI1659FWUX model portable monitor works straight out of the box (almost) if you download the driver from here:  https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu
Unzip and install it as instructed here:  https://engineerworkshop.com/blog/adding-a-portable-usb-monitor-to-ubuntu-how-to-set-up-a-displaylink-driver/

But make sure your laptop has two USB 3.0 ports.  Mine has 2 next gen 3.2 which are backwards compatible so no squiggly lines, just works and I am able to use portrait orientation and landscape.

Comment: It stopped working all of a sudden.