# how do to install the display drivers for a displaylink usb monitor on 13.04?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, displaylink

How do I install the display drivers for a displaylink usb monitor?

The monitor connected with the displaylink device has the following messages on the display:

```
[   10.723468] usb 3-1.1: device descriptor read/8, error 110
[   13.853141] nouveau E[   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] 0x8569[]: unknown opcode 0xc9
```

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on a new macbook pro with the NVIDIA GK107M [GeForce GT 650M Mac Edition] graphics card running on the open source Nouveau X.org X server display driver.

http://libdlo.freedesktop.org/wiki/ has links to drivers and stuff but no guide for  ubuntu versions passed 9.10. i was able to install and test the monitor with libdlo from that page so i figure that it is possible but i do not understand how to install the proper x-drivers to get the display to work normally.

synaptic has no results for a search for displaylink.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Strangely enough, my usb monitor used to work on 12.10 (although with a manually upgraded kernel if it makes a difference). Once I upgraded to 13.04, the only place the monitor gets recognized is as a usb device. I tried manually downloading and installing a .deb package found at http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/xserver-xorg-video-displaylink. This in turn, produces an error (Dependency not satisfiable: xorg-video-abi-11).

EDIT: I do remember a xserver-xorg-video-displaylink in 12.10 and having to manually install it.

Comment: This is not so much an answer, but a comment. I too have not been able to use my displaylink VGA adapter since 12.04. On a wimp, recently I tried fedora 18 (off the live cd), and to my surprise, (1) the system detected the displaylink adapter, (2) the displaylink screen mirrored the main display as soon as I activated this secondary display output, and (3) extended desktop worked after I installed arandr. No tweaking whatsoever. Is it possible to compare the difference between F18 and 13.04 and reverse engineer the changes?