# USB display adapter with linux/ubuntu drivers?

Tags: usb, display, external-monitor, displayport

I want to use my external monitor's resolution fully (2560x1440) with a USB display adapter for my laptop. I have one with Windows drivers, are there any adapter with linux / Ubuntu drivers that can give me full resolution?

I am thinking of something like [my current USB to DisplayPort adapter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/LINDY-USB-3-0-DisplayPort-Adapter/dp/B008501KM4).

HDMI only gives 1920x1200 (am using `arandr` to achieve this easily), and my laptop haven't got displayport. But I know that the graphic card can deliver 2560x1440 digitally or through an USB adapter.

Comment: The question is a year old, but the topic may still be of interest (March 2014): Official support from DisplayLink (one of the chipset manufacturers) is still disappointing (to say the least, see https://displaylinklinuxdriver.wordpress.com/ ).<br>
Still the posting below from one device manufacturer summarizes current progress and deficiencies of the open source hackers' efforts. http://plugable.com/2014/03/06/displaylink-usb-2-0-graphics-adapters-on-linux-2014-edition HTH

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 supports it.

Comment: @ThomasLindvig Can you get 2560x1440 now with 14.04?

Comment: related http://askubuntu.com/q/40031/79266

Answer (score 3):

Right now, on Ubuntu 14.04, my Accell DisplayLink compatible adapter just works. It didn't work on 13.10.

Specs of this adapter: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0396/6837/files/J130B-001B_manual.pdf

Copied from the manual:

> This adapter features:
> -Supports up to 1920x1200 or 2048x1152 (wide) – 1920x1080 (VGA)
> -Self-powered design
> -Fully USB 2.0 compliant
> -24-bit true color

> System requirements: USB 2.0 port, 40MB hard drive space, CD-ROM, 2GHz or Dual-Core processor minimum for Windows 7,
> Vista and Mac. Windows® 7 (64/32bit), Windows Vista (64/32bit),
> Windows XP (32bit) Intel-based Apple Mac running client versions of
> Snow Leopard 10.6, Leopard 10.5, Tiger 10.4

It seems a little slow on effects, I think that is because of being USB 2, and no acceleration? Anyway I got rid of the effects and works OK

Comment: Apparently that page is a figment of your imagination :)

Comment: LOL, seems like it's no longer available... Updating with the manual